# How to build data object to pass to ajax when not know how many?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
$(function() {
    var data;
    $('.form').find('input').removeClass('error').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); // this line gives me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name1' of undefined
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            submit = false;
            return;
        }

    });
    if (ok) {
        $.post($form.data('action'), data, function(e) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
});
```

I guess this property should be defined before... but as I don't know what items could be, how can i do this?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `data` with empty object: `data = {}`

Comment: OMG! just that? on it..

Comment: Yes, it was that... Sounds silly, but post an answer i can accept

Comment: I don't think it is worth to be on SO. I would advise to close it yourself (I've already voted to close it as "simple typo issue").

Answer (score 1):

It look like you have `input` without name parameter.

Why don't you use `.serialize()`?

```
$("form").on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post( $(this).data('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(e) {
     // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: The problems is that is not a form.... so serialize doen't work...

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet In this case you can use it as `$(".form").find("input,select,textarea").serialize()` It works too